# How to print F32 with 1 dec place and a fixed width in rust

Tags: rust, printing, formatting, width

Trying to replicate the following C printf invocation

```
printf("%6.1f %6.1f %6.1f\n", x, y, z);
```

in rust and I can't find it in the docs.  I need 6 positions wide with 1 decimal place.

First time I've been stumped finding what I need there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatting strings are documented in the documentation for [`std::fmt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html).

The equivalent of `%6.1f` would be `{:6.1}`:

```
println!("{:6.1} {:6.1} {:6.1}", x, y, z);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a944a84682e7e14651e2db3f9e080b3d)

Comment: wow ... I didn't know about `std::fmt` ... Super!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it will not respect the maximum width.

```
let str = format!("{:6.1}", 123456.7); 
assert_eq!(str.len(), 8);
```

I guess in most cases it doesn't matter (but sadly sometimes does...)

Comment: The above example with C's `printf` doesn't either.  It's a different problem IMO.